# My app crushes when i run it on my phone to test it

Tags: android, kotlin

I recently started Kotlin and Android development and I want to make an app that shows car sales ads. But unfortunately when I run this app on my phone it crashes immediately.
So the main function of this app is to show carse that are on salle and you as user would be able to add more cars to sale and to show tham as well as to reserv a car and to show only reserved cars.
Here is my code

```
package com.example.autooglas

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var toolbar: ActionBar
    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{ item ->
        when (item.itemId){
            R.id.navigation_oglasi -> {
                toolbar.title="Oglasi"
                val oglasiFragment=OglasiFragment.newInstance()
                openFragment(oglasiFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true

            }
            R.id.navigation_dodaj_oglas ->{
                toolbar.title = "Dodaj Oglas"
                val dodajOglas = DodajOglasFragment.newInstance()
                openFragment(dodajOglas)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false

    }

    private fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        toolbar = supportActionBar!!
        val bottomNavigationView:BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener ( mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener )
        openFragment(OglasiFragment.newInstance())
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        tools:ignore="MissingClass" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And her is my Logcat

```
19119-19119/com.example.autooglas E/ample.autoogla: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
19119-19119/com.example.autooglas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.autooglas, PID: 19119
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.autooglas/com.example.autooglas.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.autooglas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: BottomNavigationView does not support submenus
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenu.addSubMenu(BottomNavigationMenu.java:41)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addSubMenuItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:536)
19119-19119/com.example.autooglas E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:182)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:129)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(BottomNavigationView.java:347)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:223)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:131)
            ... 28 more
19119-19119/com.example.autooglas I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19119 SIG: 9
```

navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_oglasi"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_reorder_24px"
        android:title="@string/prikazOglasa"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_rezervisani"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_reorder_24px"
        android:title="@string/rezervOglas"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dodaj_oglas"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_box_24px"
        android:title="@string/dodajOglas"
        />

    <menu />
</menu>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the library for BottomNaviagationView and suppressed the error using `tools:ignore="MissingClass"` which allowed it to compile despite the library being missing. Delete that and [add the library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

Comment: I have added the library implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>' and the problem is still there.

Comment: replace the version by the last Version like this `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'`

Comment: Does your navigtation.xml have submenus (nested menus)?

Comment: i added navigation.xml so you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
> BottomNavigationView does not support submenus

In your menu you have a subMenus at the end of your menu just remove it and it should work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_oglasi"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_reorder_24px"
        android:title="@string/prikazOglasa"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_rezervisani"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_reorder_24px"
        android:title="@string/rezervOglas"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dodaj_oglas"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_box_24px"
        android:title="@string/dodajOglas"
        />

   <!-- Remove this line  <menu /> -->

</menu>
```